# wxPython- "no module named Panel" error

Tags: wxpython

I am writing a GUI application using wxPython . But every time i am getting "no module named Panel" error. Can anyone suggest why..
My code is this

```
class Player1(wx.Frame):
    def _init_(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame._init_(self, parent, id, title, size=(350,300))
        self.panel =wx.Panel(self)
```

I am using Python 2.7. 
I tried uninstalling and then re-installing wxPython twice but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a runnable example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the code below, if any error occurs do let me know:

**Code:**

```
import wx

class Player1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        myButton = wx.Button(myPanel, -1, 'Download', size=(100,50), pos=(20,20))
        self.Show(True)
app = wx.App()
frame = Player1(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Image')
app.MainLoop()
```